# $\sqrt x + \sqrt y + \sqrt z \geq xy + xz+ yz$ when $x+y+z = 3$ for $x, y, z> 0$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

From this closed question: [Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers that $x+y+z=3$. Prove: $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} \ge xy+yz+xz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778591/let-x-y-z-be-positive-real-numbers-that-xyz-3-prove-sqrtx-sqrty)

Show that for $x, y, z> 0$ such that $x+y+z = 3$:

$$\sqrt x + \sqrt y + \sqrt z \geq xy + xz+ yz$$

**My attempt:**

My first idea was to use cauchy schwarz, but that leads to a bound that is too coarse (for example take $x=3-2\epsilon, y=\epsilon, z=\epsilon$):

$$xy + yz + zx \leq x^2+y^2+z^2$$

I also tried looking at rearrangements of $xy + yz + zx$ but this led to similarly coarse bounds.

Finally I noticed that the constraint looks like the points along a circle if we use the substitution:

$$u = \sqrt 3 \sin\theta\cos\phi, v= \sqrt 3 \sin\theta\sin\phi, w = \sqrt 3 \cos\theta$$

So that: $u^2 + v^2 +w^2 = 3$. But after some work, I still havent made much progress:

$$\sqrt 3 \sin\theta\cos\phi + \sqrt 3 \sin\theta\sin\phi+ \sqrt 3 \cos\theta
\stackrel{show}{\geq} 3^2 (\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi\cos^2\theta)\\
= 3^2\sin^2\theta(\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\theta)$$

I tried to apply some double angle identities, but showing the inequality for all $\theta, \phi$ seems difficult still.

Comment: Yes, how do you find these? I tried approach0